# Any java Static Code analyzer that can find memory leak java code?

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, profiling, profiler, static-code-analysis

Is there any Java Static Code Analyzer that can detect code that could possibly cause a memory leak ? I understand that JVM profilers are used for this purpose, but that does not helps us to put the checkpoint during development itself.

Educating developers about best practice is on one side, but how do i put an automated process as a checkpoint here ?

Any thoughts or recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my researcher point of view, the closest thing I can think of is `COSTA`: http://costa.ls.fi.upm.es/

This is a tool that, using static analysis, computes the amount of memory used by programs/methods. Maybe the developers (feel free to ask, they are nice people) can tell you if `COSTA` is a good choice for your needs (or maybe they know something better).